# WP Query filter by ACF field don't work

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm having an issue with WP query filtered by ACF Post Object Field.
I have to query the 'post' filtered by 'author' acf field.
i'm using this code but this don't work

```
$post_type_query  = new WP_Query(
    array (  
        'post_type'      => 'post',                 
        'posts_per_page' => 3,
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'author',
                'value' => 'prova'
                )
            )
        ) 
    );
```

Thereis one article on wordpress post with 'prova' author, but the query return empty.
I can't understand why

Thanks

Comment: Looks like you're missing the relation part of the meta query. like 'meta_query' => array( 'relation' => '=', array... https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I tryed 
     'meta_query' => array(
      'relation' => '=',
      array(
             'key' => 'author',          
             'value' => 'prova'         
          )
      )

and 

     'meta_query' => array(
      array(
             'key' => 'author',
                    'compare' => '=',
             'value' => 'prova'         
          )
      )
but still don't work

Comment: Your second example should be the one that works. Sometimes WP_Query can be messed up by plugins. do you happen to have relevanassi installed? Otherwise I can help you on how to bypass with a sql query

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$postData = new WP_Query(array(  
        'post_type' => 'post',                 
        'posts_per_page' => 3,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'author',
                'value' => 'prova',
                'compare' => '='   // or if you want like then use 'compare' => 'LIKE'
                )
            )
        ) 
    ); 

if($postData->have_posts()):
    while ($postData->have_posts()): $postData->the_post();
        echo "Post Title";
        the_title();
        echo '<div class="entry-content">';
        the_content();
        echo '</div>';  
    endwhile;
endif;
```